# Tearraform : Unable to point out the parent resource created in same loop and getting Cycle error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

New to terraform. Trying to create api gateway resources with loop. Below is the structure of API

```
/test
   |
    /testchild
        POST
```

So, I want to create 2 resources with for loop. Below is the code snippets

**ag.tf**

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "demo" {
  name        = "demo-api"
  description = "This is demo"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "res" {
  
  for_each = var.resources
    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.demo.id
    parent_id   = each.value.parent ? aws_api_gateway_resource.res[each.value.parent_resource].id : var.parent_id 
    path_part   = each.key

  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_rest_api.demo.id
  ]
}
```

**vars.tf**

```
variable "resources" {
    default = {
        "test" = {
            "parent" : false
        },
        "testchild" = {
            "parent" : true,
            "parent_resource" : "test"
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below error while `terraform plan` command.

> Error: Cycle: aws_api_gateway_resource.res["testchild"],
> aws_api_gateway_resource.res["test"]

Can someone guide me how to reference the id of created resource in the loop ?

TIA

Comment: Your error message points at a cyclical dependency. Did you want assistance with the error, or with referencing the exported resource attribute, or both?

Comment: I need help specifically on line number 
 parent_id   = each.value.parent ? aws_api_gateway_resource.res[each.value.parent_resource].id : var.parent_id

Comment: how can I reference the id generated for test resource in the same loop

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in Terraform are between whole resource blocks (in the Terraform sense), not between individual instances of those resources, because Terraform must build the dependency graph before evaluating the `count` or `for_each` expressions in order to establish which instances exist. All actions on instances of a particular resource conceptually happen concurrently, although in practice Terraform might serialize them (in no specific order) to limit the number of simultaneous actions.

Therefore in effect you've made this resource refer to itself, and hence Terraform reported a dependency cycle. The Terraform language is not a good fit for this sort of recursive data structure because Terraform requires all structures to be finite. This is one of the tradeoffs of the Terraform's declarative DSL compared to general-purpose languages.

Since the API Gateway API model is inherently a recursive data structure, unfortunately it's typically necessary to write it out as explicit resources in order to correctly represent the dependences between them, because it wouldn't be valid to create all of the `aws_api_gateway_resource` objects simultaneously.

Fortunately, [the `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api) has an alternative method for creating all of the sub-objects of a rest API, by providing an OpenAPI definition to its `body` argument. In that case, creating the entire API structure is a single operation as far as Terraform is concerned, and then API Gateway internally deals with the various separate operations to represent all of those constructs.

The OpenAPI structure is also easier to work with in Terraform because it's has flat mapping from URL templates to resource definitions, rather than a recursive structure with resources nested inside other resources. That makes it practical to, where needed, dynamically construct the `paths` object using a Terraform [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) if you need to accept the definition of the resources and their methods in a different shape than the OpenAPI schema expects.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated response. But with the OpenAPI approach, I feel that it would require plugging the integration request and response part everywhere. Also, I would require to configure method-level settings. Not sure how that could be achieved. But anyway I started with the modular approach to minimize the code duplications

Comment: It's been several years since I worked with API Gateway so my memory is incomplete, but when I was last using it all of the API Gateway features I needed were representable via [the API Gateway OpenAPI Extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions.html).